# Creating scratch table with partition by date range

Tags: python, python-2.7, hive, presto, pyhive

I am trying to create a scratch table using the below query, I am trying to modify it to create table with partition by dates

```
create table scratch.myTable
        as (
        select 
            concat(eid,'_',group) as eid_group,
            name,
            test
        from 
            test_logs 
        where 
            regexp_like(eid, '[A-Z0-9]{22}') and 
            (regexp_like(group, '[a-z0-9]{8}') OR group = '') and
            line_type = 'test' and
            date between '2018-09-27' and '2018-09-30' and
            eid NOT IN ('123456789','ABCDEFF')
        ) WITH (partitioned_by sequence('2018-09-27','2018-09-30'))
```

this query creates a scratch table on s3 and dumps everything as orc files. I am trying to `partition` this table by date range

Could someone help me with the query?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing the "with" with an "over"?

```
create table scratch.myTable
        as (
        select 
            concat(eid,'_',group) as eid_group,
            name,
            test
        from 
            test_logs 
        where 
            regexp_like(eid, '[A-Z0-9]{22}') and 
            (regexp_like(group, '[a-z0-9]{8}') OR group = '') and
            line_type = 'test' and
            date between '2018-09-27' and '2018-09-30' and
            eid NOT IN ('123456789','ABCDEFF')
        ) over(partition by date)
```